# Cannot Read property error in Lightining component code

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to redirect from child object (Primary_Terms__c) to parent record detail object(Acquisition_Deal) page using lightining component code

> my apex class:

```
public class  acquisitiondeallightningcntrl 

  {    
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Primary_Terms__c> getdealid(){

    return[SELECT Id,Acquisition_Deal__c FROM Primary_Terms__c];
 }}
```

> Lightining component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="acquisitiondeallightningcntrl">
<aura:attribute name="deal" type="Acquisition_Deal__c[]"/>

   <aura:registerEvent name="navEvt" type="force:navigateToSObject"/>
     <aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigate}"/>


            <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
               <table class="slds-p-around_x-small slds-text-body_small slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout " >
                   <thead>
                      </thead> 
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.deal}" var="e">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" >
                        <td><lightning:button variant="brand" label="Acquisition Deal" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />                       
                        </td>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate slds-text-align--right" >
                            <a target="_blank" href="{!'/'+e.Id}">{!e.Name}</a>                                 
                            </div>
                            </td>
                           </tr>            
                         </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</aura:component>
```

> Controller:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {


var action = component.get("c.getdealid");


action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.deal", response.getReturnValue());
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
    }
});

// Send action off to be executed
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},

navigate:function(component){

var idx= event.currentTarget.id;
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
"recordId": idx,
"slideDevName": "detail"

 });
  navEvt.fire(); 
}   

 })
```

I am Getting Error:

> Uncaught Action failed: c:Redirectingthepage$controller$navigate
>   [Cannot read property 'current Target' of undefined]

please anyone help me to resolve this error and also for redirecting the parent page

Comment: try like this:   var test = event.currentTarget;...Let me know still you are facing that error

Comment: only event.currentTarget? @AnnappaPH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error here.

```
var idx= event.currentTarget.id;
```

You are trying to access Id here from the current record. You can't access Id using this way. Also you didn't define event as parameter so you are getting error

```
Cannot read property 'current Target' of undefined
```

You can get Id: First pass Id in class attribute of button

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Acquisition Deal" class="{!e.Id}" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />
```

and then in Controller

```
navigate: function(component,event){
        console.log(event.getSource().get("v.class"));
```

This will give you Id which you can use in your code.

Comment: @SFDCdeveloper Check in method parameter I have added event. Second I didn't use `currentTarget` so you might getting this error in some where else.

Comment: Thank you,Now  Page doesn't exist error is coming @Tushar sharma

Comment: where i am doing mistake?@Tushar Sharma

Comment: @SFDCdeveloper Try to print the Id in log and access that in browser.

Comment: @SFDCdeveloper If you have followed my code you are printing the Id `console.log(event.getSource().get("v.class"));` here. Just try to access this Id in browser.

Comment: @SFDCdeveloper you are asking very basic question. I suggest you to try some [Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics)  to get basic of Lightning.

Comment: please see this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212869/uncaught-exception-in-lightning-component?noredirect=1#comment321927_212869,still i am not able to get the answer @Tusharsharma

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

I think you missed "event" in your method, that may causes error

```
  navigate:function(component,event,helper){
   var test = event.currentTarget.id;
 }
```

Comment: Now  Page doesn't exist error is coming @Annappa PH

Comment: where i am doing mistake? @Annappa PH

Comment: have you tried my code.?

Comment: yes ,but  Page doesn't exist error is coming  @Annappa PH

Comment: now you are raising different question..please post new question for that...thanks